# Facebook payment callback in Java

Tags: java, facebook, httprequest, facebook-credits

I have a Facebook app with server side on java. I created test callback using HttpRequestHandler. The problem is when I'm getting payments_get_items, Facebook do not accept Json I've sent, and gives this error: 
"Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again."
Here is Json I'm sending:

```
Integer goldNum = o.get("item_id").getAsInt();
Integer creditsNum = building.getBuy().get(goldNum);

item.addProperty("title", "Buy gold");
item.addProperty("price", creditsNum);
item.addProperty("description", "Buy " + goldNum + " gold!");

JsonObject returnData = new JsonObject(); 
returnData.add("content", item);
returnData.addProperty("method", method);

response.getWriter().write(returnData.toString());
response.getWriter().close();
    return;
```

Here is what says log, when I'm logging returnData: {"content":{"title":"Buy gold","price":50,"description":"Buy 65 gold!"},"method":"payments_get_items"}. What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to get more detailed explanation from Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content type to `application/json`:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(returnData.toString());
response.getWriter().close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't help.